# Extract 3 hourly GLDAS data at particular point of time on daily time step from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series, nasa

The GLDAS data is at 3 hourly timesteps starting from 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, and 24 UTC.
and I want to extract the time series of Downward short-wave radiation flux at 12 UTC only for each day as it is maximum at noon only.

Here is the snapshot of the [script](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/f92d44a0314dea47e6fac73187123d5e)

```
var startDate = '2012-01-01'
var endDate = '2012-01-15'
var selected_band = 'SWdown_f_tavg'

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
                .filterBounds(Haryana)
                .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
                .select(selected_band)
                  
var meanImage = dataset.mean().clip(Haryana);
print(meanImage);

var RadiationVis = {
  min: 1.0,
  max: 700.0,
  palette: ['001137', '0aab1e', 'e7eb05', 'ff4a2d', 'e90000'],
};

Map.setCenter(76, 30, 7);
Map.addLayer(meanImage, RadiationVis, 'Radiation');

var shown = true; 
var opacity = 0.1; 
var nameLayer = 'Haryana Districts'; 
var visParams = {color: 'white'}; 
Map.addLayer(Haryana, visParams, nameLayer, shown, opacity);

var chart =
    ui.Chart.image
        .seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection: dataset,
          band: selected_band,
          regions: Haryana,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          scale: 25000,
          seriesProperty: 'DISTRICT',
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setOptions({
          title: 'GLDAS-2.1: Global Land Data Assimilation System',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Downward short-wave radiation flux (W/m^2)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718',
               '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201',
               '004C00', '023B01', '012E01', '011D01', '011301'],
        });
print(chart);
```

The current output with this code is in this format with 8 values for each day
but I want a single value at 12 UTC for each day

```
system:time_start   KURUKSHETRA MAHENDRAGARH    MEWAT   PALWAL  PANCHKULA   PANIPAT
Jan 1, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
Jan 1, 2012             46.304      46.956      49.193   47.941   44.053    48.961
Jan 1, 2012            443.498      437.244     389.44   381.904  440.902   444.416
Jan 1, 2012            542.422      458.607     338.077  365.764  551.739   525.345
Jan 1, 2012            181.264      191.988     102.175  115.053  191.332   152.894
Jan 1, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0                   
Jan 1, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
Jan 1, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
Jan 2, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
Jan 2, 2012            47.126       47.315      53.37    54.589   45.564    49.643
Jan 2, 2012            446.354      439.411     410.905  399.168  442.485   449.459
Jan 2, 2012            584.332      581.472     424.019  371.925  517.522   584.171
Jan 2, 2012            209.83       224.045     195.343  192.748  202.499   209.414
Jan 2, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
Jan 2, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
Jan 2, 2012                0          0           0       0         0          0
```

How to do so?

Also, the script gives an error when I increase the time period beyond 15 days.
Is there any way possible to export its CSV to drive with extended-time period like 10-15 years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, for your dates range, you have 112 images in your Image Collection (one image each 3 hours or 8 images per day). As you need for each day noon image only, you can filter your dataset with following method:

```
.filterMetadata('start_hour', 'equals', 12)
```

Code snippet would look as follows:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
                .filterBounds(Haryana)
                .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
                .filterMetadata('start_hour', 'equals', 12)
                .select(selected_band);
```

So, this will produce 112/8 = 14 images only; selecting your at noon desired images. Complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/97e2858442586069e3080f197cd9f369).

After running it in GEE code editor, I got result of following picture:

[image]

It can be observed (red rectangle) that all selected images in your dataset are at noon images; as expected.